# Azure Function App - connection string error

Tags: azure-functions

I have an Azure App that is running every 5 seconds but when i hit Run in the **Code+Test** tab it throws an exception relating to the connection string :

```
    2020-10-31T15:28:59  No new trace in the past 4 min(s).
    2020-10-31T15:29:48.458 [Information] Script for function 'TimerTrigger1' changed. Reloading.
    2020-10-31T15:29:48.629 [Information] Compilation succeeded.
    2020-10-31T15:30:11.399 [Information] Executing 'Functions.TimerTrigger1' (Reason='This function 
    was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=861df674-b2f8-454a-8d67-4960398a0592)
    2020-10-31T15:30:11.408 [Error] Executed 'Functions.TimerTrigger1' (Failed, Id=861df674-b2f8- 
    454a-8d67-4960398a0592, Duration=16ms)Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')
```

The Connection string was already configured when i was setting up the output binding for the function. The function writes a log file to Azure Blob Storage.
What i have i done

1. I have verified that the Storage Account indeed has a container
   added.
2. I have also verified my App Setting for the storage account
   connection string

After some deep digging i have found out that there is a JSON config file  where i can **edit** some stuff about the Function App. I have however navigated the whole breadth of the function in Azure portal but i cannot see that file anywhere even though the instruction [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/create-serverless-logic-with-azure-functions/4-creating-and-executing-an-azure-function) specifically say that ***To view and edit the contents of function.json in the Azure portal, click the Advanced editor option on the Integrate tab of your function.***

In my run.csx i have:

```
    using System;

    public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer,out string outputBlob, ILogger log)
    {
log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
outputBlob="Hello world ! Function is running every 5 seconds";
   }
```

What am i missing ?

I thought this was supposed to be handled implicitly in the background. From my understanding i only need to worry about connection strings when i have more complex logic for the Function App like EF connections.

Comment: Please show your function.json

Comment: I cannot see it anywhere in Azure Portal. looked everywhere

Comment: Hi, have a look of this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPiuR.png).

Comment: Please share your function.json as Bowman mentioned.

Comment: {
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */5 * * * *"
    },
    {
      "name": "outputBlob",
      "direction": "out",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "outcontainer/{rand-guid}",
      "connection": "storageaccountwinsea3a5_STORAGE"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
} @HuryShen

Comment: {
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */5 * * * *"
    },
    {
      "name": "outputBlob",
      "direction": "out",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "outcontainer/{rand-guid}",
      "connection": "storageaccountwinsea3a5_STORAGE"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
} @BowmanZhu

Comment: It appears the connection is already there. Should i rename connection to connectionString or add a new property

Comment: Have you added a variable `storageaccountwinsea3a5_STORAGE` with the connection string as its value in "Application settings" of your function ?